# Help proving that this structure is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The exact wording of the question is as follows:

Let $S$ be a set with an operation that assigns to each ordered pair $(a,b)$ of elements of $S$ to an element $a/b$ of $S$ in such a way that:

1. there is an element $1\in S$, such that $a/b=1$ if and only if $a=b$.
2. for any elements $a,b,c\in S$, $ (a/c)/(b/c)=a/b$

Show that $S$ is a group under the product defined by $ab=a/(1/b)$

Firstly I noted $(a/1)/1=(a/1)/(1/1)=a/1$ and thus $((a/1)/1)/(a/1)=1$ and $(a/1)/a=1$ meaning $a/1=a$

From there I could begin to prove the group axioms

Identity: $$1a=1/(1/a)=(a/a)/(1/a)=a/1=a$$
$$a1=a/(1/1)=a/1=a$$
Inverse: $$a(1/a)=a/(1/(1/a))=a/((a/a)/(1/a))=a/(a/1)=a/a=1$$
$$(1/a)a=(1/a)/(1/a)=1$$
Where I have really hit a brick wall is associativity. Decomposing the product defintion means showing $a(bc)=(ab)c$ is equivalent to  showing $$a/(1/(b/(1/c)))=(a/(1/b))/(1/c)$$At the moment I have no idea and any help would be vastly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe look at it backwards: If we *have* a group  and define $a/b:=ab^{-1}$, do we need associativity to show $(ac^{-1})(bc^{-1})^{-1}=ab^{-1}$? Can this be exploted for the opposite direction we need here?

Comment: I'm giving it a go at the moment, It might be fruitful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few more "obvious" rules can be shown:
Using $x^{-1}=1/x$ and hence $1/(x^{-1})=x$, we have 
$$a\cdot b^{-1}=a/(1/b^{–1})=a/b$$
Also, 
$$ (a/b)^{–1}=(a\cdot b^{-1})^{-1}=b\cdot a^{–1}=b/a$$
Also 
$$(a/b)/b^{-1}=(a/b)/(1/b)=a/1=a .$$
Then 
$$ \begin{align}a\cdot (b\cdot c)&=a\cdot (c^{-1}\cdot b^{-1})^{-1}\\&=a/(c^{-1}\cdot b^{-1})\\&=a/(c^{-1}/b)\\&=(a/b^{-1})/((c/b)/b^{-1})\\&=(a/b^{-1})/c^{-1}\\&=(a\cdot b)\cdot c\end{align}$$

Comment: Is the $c$ in the thrid last line meant to be a $c^{-1}$? Otherwise this makes sense and works well. Thank you